# How to see if two variables are correlated when the response variable is binary

Tags: correlation

I am not formally trained in statistics so please bear with me. I am interested in seeing if the explanatory variable in an experiment is correlated with the response variable. However the response variable is binary (pass/fail). What would the appropriate test for relationship be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you simply seek a correlation coefficient then you can compute the Point-Biserial Correlation Coefficient, and this will produce a statistic in the range of (-1, 1)

However, since you mention the *response* and *explanatory* variables, I suspect you would like to fit a regression model. An appropriate model in this case is Logistic Regression, a specific type of a generalized linear model, which will provide an odds ratio.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please provide some more information? Have you tried any correlation tests? Parametric or non-parametric, and if so, was the result unsatisfactory?

<s>Depending on your data you could try [Pearson Correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_correlation_coefficient), [Spearman Correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spearman%27s_rank_correlation_coefficient) or another test. If your using python check the functions provided by scipy [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/stats.html#correlation-functions)</s> **see Robert Long's comment and reply**

Furthermore, please do a more comprehensive search on this stack. This has too be a duplicate question. (e.g [Correlation issue](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/228458/how-to-handle-predictors-that-are-highly-correlated-to-the-response?rq=1))

Comment: Pearson's correlation and Spearman's correlation are both innapropriate when one of the variables is binary.